# Let $U$ be a subset of $\mathbb{R}^2\setminus\{0\}$, $i_\ast(\pi_1(U))=0$ or $\mathbb{Z}$

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

Let $U$ be a connected open subset of the punctured plane $\mathbb{R}^2\setminus\{0\}$ and $i\colon U\to \mathbb{R}^2\setminus\{0\}$ the inclusion mapping, $\pi_1(U)$ the fundamental group of $U$. Can we deduce that $i_\ast(\pi_1(U))$ is either $0$ or $\mathbb{Z}$? Can it happen that $\pi_1(U)=2\mathbb{Z},3\mathbb{Z},\dots$?

Is it correct that we can define holomorphic branch of square root of $z$ on $U$ if and only if we can define holomorphic branch of $\log z$ on $U$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It suffices to show that the image is either $\mathbb{Z}$ or $0$ for any closed, bounded subset, since any loop is contained inside a closed, bounded subset.

Let $B$ be the bounded subset. We construct a map $P \rightarrow B$ that when composed with the inclusion of $B$ into the punctured plane $P$ is a retraction of $\pi_1(B)$ onto a $\mathbb{Z}$ retract. This implies that there is no $n \neq 0$ so that $na$ is in the summand when $a$ is not in the summand which implies that the image of the generator of this summand in $\pi_1(P)$ is either $0$ or a generator of $\pi_1(P)$.
Since $B$ is bounded, there is a circle $C$ containing it. Define a map $f:C \rightarrow B$ by sending $p$ to the element of $B$ that is closest to $p$ on the line from $p$ to the origin (if no such point exists the fundamental group of $B$ is trivial).

Now let $g: P \rightarrow C$ be the map radially deforming $P$ into $C$. Then $f \circ g \circ i$ is a retraction onto something homeomorphic to a circle, so its fundamental group is $\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: Worth noting is that this extends to higher dimensions and higher homotopy groups.

Comment: I feel that $f\circ g\circ i$ maybe not continuous, since the set $B$ maybe not convex.

Comment: @HGF ah I had imagined being closed was enough but I see it isn’t.

Comment: you can replace the set with the punctured convex closure, and this works. Then you can reduce the problem to the inclusion of the set into its punctured convex closure.